# Get the property of an item in array

Tags: php

Im trying to get the values of an array, but dont know why i cant, can someone help me? this is how the array start:

```
 $usersTable = {"userStats": [{
                   "type": "user",
                   "name": "John Stripes",
                   "roll": "moderator",
                   "entries": [.....
```

im doing a var_dump($usersTable) and i can acces to the first level, but then im stuck, it returns "Trying to get property of non-object".

At the first level, this is what returns:

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#90 (5) { ["type"]=> string(4) "user" ["name"]=> string(12) "John Stripes" ["roll"]=> string(9) "moderator" ["entries"]=> array(191) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#91 (9) { ...
```

im trying to get in and return something like $usersTable->userStats->name

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`userStats` is an array, not an object. If you want to access objects in this array, you must use their index in the array, e.g. like this:

```
$usersTable->userStats[0]->name // name property of first object in userStats
```

Comment: $usersTable->userStats works fine, tried $usersTable->userStats[0]->name but it returns "Cannot access empty property"

Comment: Are you sure you're using `$usersTable->userStats[0]->name`, and not maybe `$usersTable->$userStats[0]->name` or `$usersTable->userStats[0]->$name`? Just asking, because the error message could mean an undefined dynamic variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
echo $usersTable['userStats']['name'];
```

Comment: it returns me "Cannot access empty property" :(